# How to add an input if it does not exist with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code to insert an element:

```
$('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="admin" value="true">')
```

But running multiple times adds multiple elements.

What is a succinct way of adding only if it does not exist?

Comment: Side note; possible code smell around security concerns with having a hidden variable define the state of if a user is an admin.  This is open to being changed by users with any level of ability to inspect the dom and change things.

Comment: @Taplar - Haha, that is by design. I came up with an interesting input name for the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator inside your function :

```
$('form').append(($('form input[name=admin]').length > 0) ? '' : '<input type="hidden" name="admin" value="true">');
```

Here, if there's more than 0 `<input name='admin'>`, it appends nothing in the form.

It's a bit ugly code but It can work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Remove if present and then add

```
  var parentForm = $('form');
  parentForm.find("input[name=admin]").remove();
  parentForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="admin" value="true">')
```

To add an element only if absent you can have something like this

```
  var parentForm = $('form');
  var inputAdmin = parentForm.find("input[name=admin]");
  if(inputAdmin.length==0)
     parentForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="admin" value="true">')
```